# Convert ByteArray into png image and add it to ImageView in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have the Image ByteArray and want to convert the byte array into png image and add in ImageView as you see in the below code.

```
 byte[] imageBytes =  webClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(uri);


 ImageView view = new ImageView(this.Context);

  //Here need to add the converted image into ImageView
  view.SetImageSource();
```

I achieved this, by converting ImageBytes into a bitmap and add the bitmap in ImageView. But it has some memory problem. As I adding more no.of times frequently in my source, I couldn't use a bitmap to add in ImageView due to the memory exception.

So please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: You should rescale while constructing a bitmap. You get memory problems because the resolution of your pictures is too big. You could also use smaller images. Talking about .png makes no sense.

Comment: did anything work for you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by creating the bitmap from Stream to do that use this:

```
using(var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
{
    var bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(ms);
    // ...
    // rest of your logic here...
    // ...
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I am getting this exception Android.Graphics.Bitmap does not contain a constructor that takes a one argument

Comment: The bitmap was from the System.Drawing namespace. I'll check the documentation and update the code

Answer (score 2):

It should be as easy as calling

```
var bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
```

[Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray Method](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray/p/System.Byte[]/System.Int32/System.Int32/Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory+Options/)

> Decode an immutable bitmap from the specified byte array.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - data
>
>   - byte array of compressed image data
> - offset
>
>   - offset into imageData for where the decoder should begin parsing.
> - length
>
>   - the number of bytes, beginning at offset, to parse
> - opts
>
>   - null-ok; Options that control downsampling and whether the image should be completely decoded, or just is size returned.